# How can I restrict background data in Android programmatically?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I am trying to make an app which stops individual apps from data usage. I checked everywhere and got nothing.

I have tried [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/data-saver.html) but it is for showing data usage but not how to restrict the background data.

```
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
// Checks if the device is on a metered network
if (connMgr.isActiveNetworkMetered()) {
  // Checks user’s Data Saver settings.
  switch (connMgr.getRestrictBackgroundStatus()) {
    case RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_STATUS_ENABLED:
    // Background data usage is blocked for this app. Wherever possible,
    // the app should also use less data in the foreground.

    case RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_STATUS_WHITELISTED:
    // The app is whitelisted. Wherever possible,
    // the app should use less data in the foreground and background.

    case RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_STATUS_DISABLED:
    // Data Saver is disabled. Since the device is connected to a
    // metered network, the app should use less data wherever possible.
  }
} else {
  // The device is not on a metered network.
  // Use data as required to perform syncs, downloads, and updates.
}
```

Comment: why so many downvotes? the question is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it programmatically. No application should be able to disable or enable data usage, it would be a security issue.

The only thing you can do is prompt user to do it by opening the requested page in system settings.

Comment: In android settings it's showing it will restrict background data... i want when i toggle on for some particular app , that app should not get internet in forground as well as background from wifi and mobile app. Is this possible or not.

Comment: @TapanPatro, it is not possible, and it should not be possible.

Comment: How .. In iOS this option is there .. settings-->mobile data--> and toggle on and off ??